# How to remake MYSQL query for mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How to make it under a mongoose?

```
SELECT x, y, z, 100*(((X*(100-Z)/100)/Y)-1) as total
FROM your table
ORDER BY total desc
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Question should be "How to make it in mongoDB?"

Comment: @peacetype I don't even know how to start it ..

Comment: @Ruslan [you need read about $aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

Comment: @JackNavaRow I read, but did not understand how to insert my formula. Can you tell me please?

Comment: Try to add Collection Model, Some data and the data expected